# How can I automatically create BigQuery tables from my Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to create a job which runs at say 2 am every morning. This job must create a BigQuery table by reading my files from Cloud Storage bucket. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the file format? How do you generate the table name? How many files do you have? Do you want to append to existing tables or truncate them?

Comment: The files are firestore exports (.export_metadata). These are my firestore sub collection exports. I have 4 sub collections. Each of these sub collections have 419 documents each.  I want to truncate existing table and reload them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly import your firestore backup into BigQuery. Set up a [load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#api) with the sourceFormat equal to `DATASTORE_BACKUP` (yes even for firestore) and the writeDisposition to `WRITE_TRUNCATE`

You can wrap this into a Cloud Function. You can use directly the API or the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). If you need code sample, give me your language, I will see what I can do for you.

**EDIT**

You need to import these dependencies in your package.json

```
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^4.7.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.0.1",
```

Then, here the function with statics values. You can build something more dynamic if you want (by reading the function param for example).

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const storage = new Storage();
//
const bucketName = "my_bucket" //to change
const fileExport = "path/to/my_export.export_metadata" //to change
const datasetId = "data" //to change
const tableId = "dsexport" //to change
exports.loadDSExport = async (req, res) => {

    // Configure the load job. For full list of options, see:
    // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationLoad
    const metadata = {
        sourceFormat: 'DATASTORE_BACKUP',
        autodetect: true,
        location: 'EU', // Set your correct region
        writeDisposition: "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    };

    // Load data from a Google Cloud Storage file into the table
    const [job] = await bigquery
        .dataset(datasetId)
        .table(tableId)
        .load(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileExport), metadata);
    // load() waits for the job to finish
    // Can take time, increase function timeout if needed

    // Check the job's status for errors
    const errors = job.status.errors;
    if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        //Handle error and return code here
        throw errors;
    }

    console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
    res.send(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
};
```

And then, deploy your function like this (here in private mode)

```
gcloud beta functions deploy --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http --entry-point loadDSExport --region europe-west1 loadDSExport
```

Comment: I need help writing the cloud function. Can you give me a sample cloud function that I can use to execute the bq load command? The below bq load command works through the CLI : bq --location=asia-east1 load \
--replace --source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP \
firestore.nric_test \
gs://gcp_firestore_ae1/export_20200521/all_namespaces/kind_nric_img/all_namespaces_kind_nric_img.export_metadata

Comment: What's you preferred language? Go? Node? Python? Java is coming but I can also!

Comment: Node or Java is fine

Comment: Edited with Node version @NehaShaikh

Comment: Thanks a lot @guillaume blaquiere!

Comment: any idea how can I schedule this function to run daily and export data to my BigQuery dataset in asia-east1? I need to create and run this cloud function in asia-east1 location. However, currently I see that asia-east1 is not supported by Cloud functions  :( @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: You don't care where the function run! The function simply trigger a task to BigQuery for importing data from GCS into a Table. The function location doesn't matter!

Comment: I have 2 more questions:                       1. When I am testing the above code as a cloud function, it giving me the error: Error: function execution failed. Details: res.send is not a function                                                                                                                               
2. How can I schedule this function to run daily? @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: How are you testing the function? Locally? On cloud function? If locally, can you show me how you do this?

Comment: I am testing on cloud function

Comment: It works great on my side. Are you sure that you don't have an error? It's not handled in my example.

Comment: After I comment out the line: res.send(`Job ${job.id} completed.`); the function test succeeds on cloud functions

Comment: The BigQuery table created out of this cloud function, is adding extra '__key__. app', '__key__. path','__key__. kind','__key__. name','__key__. id' fields for each of my 'Record' data type fields. These are all having nulls. I do not want to have these extra fields for every 'Record' Data Type. Is there a way to remove them from my BigQuery table? Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254007  for a detailed BigQuery schema. @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere can i get python version ?

Comment: @soheshdoshi, Create a new question and I could adapt the code in Python. It's not possible in comment, and it's not in relation with the question here!