# How to get rid of __key__ columns in BigQuery table for every 'Record' Type field?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

For every 'Record' Type of my Firestore table, BigQuery is automatically adding the '**key**' columns. I do not want to have these added for each of the 'Record' Type fields. How can I get rid of these extra columns automatically being added by BigQuery? (I want to get rid of the below columns in my BigQuery table schema highlighted in yellow)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behavior, citing Bigquery GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore):

> Each document in **Firestore** has a unique key that contains
>   information such as the document ID and the document path. BigQuery
>   creates a `RECORD` data type (also known as a `STRUCT`) for the key,
>   with nested fields for each piece of information, as described in the
>   following table.

Due to the fact that Firestore export method is fully integrated with GCP managed import and export [service](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import), you can't change this behavior, excluding `__key__.*` properties being sent for each `RECORD` field in the target Bigquery table.

I guess in your use case, Bigquery table modification action will require some hand-on intervention, since it requires [manually changing schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas) data.

In order to set up this feasibility I would encourage you to raise a service request to the vendor via Google public issue [tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).